# Копирование векторов

Tags: c++, vector

Как скопировать один вектор в другой при условии, что элементы первого имеют тип с большим диапазоном значений нежели тип элементов второго?

Причем элементы первого вектора, значения которых выходят за границы типа данных элементов второго вектора, не копировать.

Например, `vector<__int64>` скопировать в `vector<__int16>` так, чтобы в `vector<__int16>` были только те значения из `vector<__int64>`, которые лежат в диапазоне от `-32768` до `32767`.

Comment: "библиотечного" способа нет, нужно самому пройтись по массиву и добавить все нужные элементы

Comment: @YuriyOrlov это прискорбно, особенно в общем случае

Comment: Вы случайно не путаете _размерность_ и _размер_?

Comment: @VladD под размерностью имел в виду размер элементов, а не их количество

Comment: @johD: Я понял, но слово «размерность» означает не это. Например, массив размерности 2 — это двумерный массив, матрица. Массив размерности 3 — трёхмерный, кубическая структура данных. И т. д.

Comment: @VladD в смысле dimention? Как в линейной алгебре?

Comment: А что д.б. в тех местах где не влезает?

Comment: @johD: Именно так.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В одиннадцатом стандарте (*C++11*) можно наваять что-нибудь в духе:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    std::vector<__int64> vector64 = {1, 2, 3, 1234567, 5};
    std::vector<__int16> vector16(vector64.size());
    auto it = std::copy_if(vector64.begin(), vector64.end(), vector16.begin(), [&](__int64 item){ return (INT16_MIN <= item && item <= INT16_MAX); });
    vector16.resize(std::distance(vector16.begin(), it));
}
```

---

Или более общий вариант:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

// случае использования не только для целочисленных типов, а для любых конрертируемых:
//template<typename From, typename To, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<From, To>::value>::type>
template<typename From, typename To, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_integral<From>::value && std::is_integral<To>::value>::type>
void copyIfPossible(const std::vector<From>& from, std::vector<To>& to)
{
    to.clear();
    std::copy_if(from.begin(), from.end(), std::back_inserter(to), [&](const From& item){ return (std::numeric_limits<To>::min() <= item && item <= std::numeric_limits<To>::max()); });
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<__int64> vector64 = { 1, 2, 3, 1234567, 5 };

    std::vector<__int16> vector16;
    copyIfPossible(vector64, vector16);

    std::vector<double> vectorDouble;
    //copyIfPossible(vector64, vectorDouble); // ошибка компиляции
}
```

Comment: Ну это да, но вот желательно в общем случае. Когда `vector <__int64>` копируется в `vector<"любой целочисленный тип">`

Comment: @johD Обновил ответ для более общего варианта, попробуйте (или вам требуется именно для целочисленных типов, а не для конвертируемых друг в друга, тогда просто одно проверочку поменять и все).

Comment: В лямбда-выражении Вы же проверяете для __int16

Comment: @johD Ой, вот этот кусочек забыл поменять, сейчас что-нибудь придумаем.

Comment: А ещё пишет, что `enable_if_t doesn't name a template type`, хотя всё подключил и стандарт 11

Comment: @johD я на студийном 2013 компиляторе тестировал, сейчас еще гляну в каком-нибудь gcc.

Comment: На мой взгляд, вместо двух resize'ов лучше использовать back_inserter итератор

Comment: @ixSci Точно, спасибо за полезное замечание :)

Comment: кстати, чисто лингвистическое замечание: никогда англоговорящий программист не назовёт функцию `copyIfItIsPossible` — `copyIfPossible`. Я бы даже пошёл дальше и сказал бы, что так даже в тексте вряд ли напишут.

Comment: @ixSci Окей, учту на будущее :)

Answer (score 3):

для общего случая вы можете сделать шаблонную функцию с применением `numeric_limits`

```
template <typename T_FROM, typename T_TO>
std::vector<T_TO> my_copy(std::vector<T_FROM> v)
{
    static_assert(std::is_convertible<T_FROM, T_TO>::value, "cannot convert");
    std::vector<T_TO> result;
    std::for_each (v.begin(), v.end(), [&](T_FROM i)
    {
        if (std::numeric_limits<T_TO>::min() <= i && i <= std::numeric_limits<T_TO>::max())
            result.push_back(i);
    });
    return result;
}
//.....
std::vector<uint16_t> v16;
std::vector<uint64_t> v64;
//.....
v16 = my_copy<uint64_t, uint16_t>(v64);
```

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо